# Regex replace text between tags

Tags: regex, tags

How to match text between these tags ?

```
<!-- |IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE| -->
some text
<!-- |END:IF| -->
```

Thanx!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags goes here as well :)

Comment: Sorry, I need all match all block. {<!-- |IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE| --> some text <!-- |END:IF| -->} match all text this text with tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not very recommendable but

```
<!-- \|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE\| -->((\s|.)*?)<!-- \|END:IF\| -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace("/<body>([\s\S]*.*)<\/body>/",$replace,$origional);
```

this will replace whole content between body tags.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex:

```
(?<=<!-- \|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE\| -->)(\s|.)*?(?=<!-- \|END:IF\| -->)
```

Comment: Sorry, I need all match all block.

{<!-- |IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE| -->
some text
<!-- |END:IF| -->} match all text this text with tags

Comment: well, its not a good idea. Look at links above, edited my regex to match desired

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, the only special character here is the pipe '|'. So, the following regex will match (and return due to the capturing brackets (.+) ) the text you are looking for:

```
{<!-- \|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE\| -->\s*(.+)\s*<!-- \|END:IF\| -->}s
```

Note that the 's' modifier let's the regex match multiple lines, and the \s* before and after the capturing brackets means that whitespace (including line breaks) will not be included in the returned match.